# intent.putExtras(String key, Message object) throws Can't marshal non-Parcelable objects across processes

Tags: java, android, message, parcelable

This is my `WebChromeClient` in my default activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivty, PopUpActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", resultMsg);
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
```

And this is how I handle in `PopUpActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webpage);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    mCloseButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.close_button);

    // we don't care about getting a warmed webview in this case, just create a new one
    mWebView = WebViewConstructor.constructWebView(this);

    mWebViewContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_container);

    // add the webview to the container layout
    WebViewManager.attachWebViewToParentContainer(mWebView, mWebViewContainer);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        Message resultMsg = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("MESSAGE");
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
}
```

Basically, I want to pass in the WebView.WebViewTransport that's passed in as resultMsg.obj to the PopUpActivity so that he can construct the webview and handle the message. However, I get this error, caused by the line 
`intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", resultMsg)`:

```
Can't marshal non-Parcelable objects across processes.
```

Even though resultMsg is a Message class that implements Parcelable ?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code ,you use `intent.getExtras()` to get value .And `intent.getExtras()`'s return is `Bundle`,so you should use `Bundle` to transfer data .

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivty, PopUpActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", resultMsg);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mActivty, PopUpActivity.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putParcelable("MESSAGE", resultMsg);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

**Another way**

You use `intent.putExtra` to transfer `Message` ,and the `Message` is `Parcelable` .So you can use `intent.getParcelableExtra` to get value .

Change

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    Message resultMsg = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("MESSAGE");
    WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
    transport.setWebView(mWebView);
    resultMsg.sendToTarget();
```

to

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Message resultMsg = intent.getParcelableExtra("MESSAGE")
WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
transport.setWebView(mWebView);
resultMsg.sendToTarget();
```

**Note**

- If you use `Bundle` to transfer data , you must use `Bundle` to get data and deal with it .
- If you use normal `putExtra` method to transfer data , you can use the corresponding get method to get data .

Comment: Thanks for noticing the discrepancy.. As you mentioned, I'm trying to use `intent.putExtra` to transfer `Message`, and the `Message` is `Parcelable` (as it is in the original code). However, the error comes from attempting to do `intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", resultMsg);` saying `resultMsg` is not Parcelable, even though it is a Message object.

Comment: You can try both two way .

Comment: I tried the second way, and still same `Can't marshal non-Parcelable objects across processes` error:

`Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, PopUpActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("MESSAGE", resultMsg);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);`